# ZSH, colourify & autocompletion

Tags: shell, zsh, autocomplete, make

I have zsh with oh-my-zsh, I added an alias to color the `make` output using

```
alias make="colourify make"
```

but when I use it, make autocompletion does not work anymore. If I use `unalias make`, the make autocompletion works anew,

how can I force the make autocompletion to work on the alias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a work-around, try using a shell function instead:

```
make () {
    colourify make "$@"
}
```

The same completions will apply to your function as to the "real" `make` command, but your function will then take care of calling `colourify` with the given options.

Comment: This worked, but I had to replace the alias to `colourify` itself by a function:)